# Are we able to compose JavaScript equivalent objects for CSS statements?

Tags: javascript, css, css-in-js

I'm getting started with React and Material UI and I came across styling. They use something called CSS-in-JS. A little confused about using camelCase instead of kebab-case for it's properties in JavaScript.

In the link below, [CSS Properties Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference), we can see all JavaScript equivalent of the CSS properties. My question is, are we only limited to that list for the JavaScript equivalent? Could we do something like columnRuleStyle for its CSS counterpart, column-rule-style.

Please let me know what you think. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is not a React specific thing and the link you reference says that the list on the page is incomplete. Why not test in codesandbox.io?

Comment: Took me 2 minutes to test: https://codesandbox.io/embed/solitary-currying-x91xg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a react convention, but since you mention getting into react, here is what react has to say:

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

> The `style` attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased
>   properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM
>   `style` JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS
>   security holes.

AFAIK, yes, nearly all* supported CSS rules are supported, using camelCasing in JS.

* I've not found one that isn't in the 3 years I've been in react.